# Правильная конструкция условий в циклах

Tags: python, python-3.x, pep8

Допустим есть цикл

```
while True:
    any_sql_req = ... # Получаем запрос из базы данных, записей может не быть и приходит пустой ответ
    if not any_sql_req:
        time.sleep(600)
        continue

    for item in any_sql_req:
        ... # дальше код и где-то глубоко цикл ломается
```

Суть вопроса, правильное ли это оформление кода с точки зрения `PEP`?

Ведь можно (и я подозреваю, что нужно) писать так:

```
while True:
    any_sql_req = ...
    if not any_sql_req:
        time.sleep(600)
        continue
    else:
        for item in any_sql_req:
            ... # дальше код
```

Но у меня огромная вложенность (если это класс 2 табуляции, потом метод еще 2 табуляции, условия, а может быть условие в условие, try конструкции, итерации и тд и тп) и код в редакторе (ide) начинается с середины, что усложняет читабельность, да и еще по PEP длина строчки `128` символов...

Как быть в таких случаях?

Comment: Какой PEP? PEP 8?

Comment: @MarianD, я не знаю какой PEP отвечает за стили написания конструкций, если бы знал, нашёл бы информацию и не спрашивал

Comment: Здес на русском: [PEP 8 - руководство по написанию кода на Python](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html#id28), на английском: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

все нормально,

в приведённом коде `else` конструкция совершенно избыточная,

если же очень хочется использовать `if/else` конструкцию, то надо было бы делать так:

```
while True:
    any_sql_req = ...
    if not any_sql_req:
        time.sleep(600)
    else:
        for item in any_sql_req:
            ... # дальше код
```

потому что тут уже `continue` избыточен, но в данном случае визуально хуже воспринимается смысл кода

на счет PEP - проверяйте свой код на http://pep8online.com/checkresult

Comment: Пытаясь найти информацию, пишут что нужно стараться выдерживать "уровень" в таких конструкциях, дабы была лучше читабельность, спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @Алексей, главное 1)код выполнял заложенный функционал без ошибок 2)был читабельным/понятным не только вам, пункт первый у вас в обоих вариантах выполняется, а касательно пункта второго - это уже все на ваш эстетический вкус, лично мне, к примеру, нравится когда логические блоки разделены комментариями, типа перед `if not any_sql_req:` написать что-то типа `# в случае неудачи - подождать 600мсек и перейти к следующему этапу цикла`, а перед `for item in any_sql_req:` поставить свой и все - визуально программа разделена на блоки и удобно читать, а с `if/else` часто визуально плохо воспринимается

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю как насчёт PEP, а в плане рефакторинга я бы разделил на функции/методы. Не уверен за то, как у вас внешний цикл прерывается, сделал по своим предположениям, что по некоему флагу он всё же выходит из цикла по результатам обработки данных:

```
def process_data_loop:
    while True:
        req = get_sql_req()
        result = process_sql_req(req)
        if not result:
            break

def get_sql_req():
    while True:
        any_sql_req = ...
        if any_sql_req:
            return any_sql_req
        time.sleep(600)

def process_sql_req(req):
    for item in any_sql_req:
        ... # дальше код
    return result
```

Возможно, надо не выставлять флаг, а бросать прерывание во внутренней функции обработки и таким образом выходить из внешнего цикла. Зависит от дизайна, можно по-разному делать. Но с исключением внешний цикл лаконичнее будет:

```
def process_data_loop:
    while True:
        req = get_sql_req()
        process_sql_req(req)
```

Смысл правильного рефакторинга в том, чтобы не замусоривать верхние уровни абстракции деталями реализации нижних уровней.